# How to start Different Activity from Different Notification using Urban Airship Android

Tags: android

Please Reply...

If suppose i want to start 4 Different Intent from 4 Different Notification inside my IntentReciver File.

How to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have **only one push notification receiver** class.

From that class, **according to the Push notification content, start respective activities**.

Comment: Thanks for reply But How to parse Notification content. Suppose i have  different Type id for each notification so i donot know how to get that from intent in Reciver class can you please send me some sample example.

Answer (score 0):

have 4 different custom messages to be send from your server via urban airship.
and in your receiver, parse the message, and associate one message for one activity call by an intent.
that way 4 different messages can be used to call 4 different activities.

Comment: Thanks for reply But How to parse Notification content. Suppose i have  different Type id for each notification so i donot know how to get that from intent in Reciver class can you please send me some sample example.

Comment: i would suggest you to take a look at the documentations here https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Guide%3A+Android%3A+Push